# Reporting service Error when accessing TFS Admin tool 2.1

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssas

While accessing TFS Admin tool 2.1, it opens up the project but when i double click to provide access to users it give me error which says "An eeror occurred when connecting to reposting service for selected team project. To prevent any data corruption you will not be able to admistrate this project."

I check/restarted reporting service and analysis service, they running fine.
I am TFS admin.
I get same error for all the project.

What do i need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.. it was an IIS space related issue. my D: where my log sits were full. i deleted some old logs. viola! reports back on site. :)...